# Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found on Windows 10 with Apache 2.4, PHP 7.4

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, apache-config, apache-modules

**System/Software:**

- Windows 10 Pro 64 bit, Version 1909
- httpd-2.4.43-win64-VS16
- php-7.4.5-Win32-vc15-x64
- mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.20.0

**PHP Script**

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';
} else {
    echo 'Phew we have it!';
}
```

Yields: `We don't have mysqli!!!`

**phpinfo**

[image]

**php.ini directives**

```
extension_dir = "ext"
extension=mysqli
```

Looking at the `phpinfo`, it seems like `mysqlnd` is loaded, but `mysqli` is not.  I don't know how to get it loaded.

**Question**

How do I load `mysqli` module on Windows, when it seems like I already have directives in `php.ini` to have it be loaded?

**Update - I found these**

- `phpinfo()` reports: Configuration File (php.ini) Path: `C:\Windows`
- `phpinfo()` reports: Loaded Configuration File: `(none)`
- My `php.ini` file is located in `C:\php\php.ini`

When setting up previous versions of PHP Configuration File Path used to be `C:\php\php.ini`.  Move to `C:\Windows` seems to be new, and that is what threw me off.  If someone can find a proper official docs or guide where this is explained or documented, I will appreciate it.  I was not able to successfully find proper installation instructions for PHP just yet, and was going by memory of my previous experiences.

Comment: so, just after posting it I was able to resolve this issue.  
My `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` was blank, and for whatever reason, PHP was looking for `php.ini` file in `C:\Windows`, and not in `C:\php`, where I usually had it in the past.  I moved my `php.ini` file into `C:\Windows`, and it seems like we are happy again.

Answer (score 1):

My `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` was blank, and for whatever reason, PHP was looking for `php.ini` file in `C:\Windows`, and not in `C:\php`, where I usually had it in the past.  I moved my `php.ini` file into `C:\Windows`, and it seems like we are happy again.